# ROUNDDOWN TIME, Power Bi

Tags: sql, powerbi

I am looking at using the `ROUNDDOWN` function.

I want to `ROUNDDOWN` time in all transactions made in a specific hours throughout the day. Say there were 15 transactions between 9:00 am and 9:59 am.. 9:01:02am, 9:10:05am, 9:45:52am etc.. All rounddown to 9:00:00am or 9:00am so I can measure day by the hour.

I have tried

```
= ROUNDDOWN(Query[TIME], 1) //which messes up the result



= ROUNDDOWN(Query[TIME], "1:00") //which gives me an error, cannot convert value
```

The time is in  `H:mm:ss`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are doing this in PowerBI with DAX you can use `HOUR` to extract the only the hour-part from a time-column:

```
TIME(HOUR(Query[TIME]);0;0)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, at first did not work with the ;0 ;0  but I tried it changing it to ,0,0 and it worked like a charm, thank you so much.

Comment: @Carlos yes, it depends on what language you have the office suite installed in, so my version uses `;` as argument separator and `,` as decimal separator.